# Is it possible to interfere with or circumvent Google's GWT JS code generation?

Tags: gwt

I'm interested in using a static iframe instead of the dynamically one that is created by default.

```
  var frameInjected;
  function maybeInjectFrame(){
    if (!frameInjected) {
      frameInjected = true;
      var iframe = $doc.createElement($intern_36);
      iframe.src = $intern_37;
      iframe.id = $intern_1;
      iframe.style.cssText = $intern_38;
      iframe.tabIndex = -1;
      $doc.body.appendChild(iframe);
      $stats && $stats({moduleName:$intern_1, sessionId:$sessionId, subSystem:$intern_2, evtGroup:$intern_8, millis:(new Date).getTime(), type:$intern_39});
      iframe.contentWindow.location.replace(base + initialHtml);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible to customise GWT's JS generation.  Research GWT linkers.